# How to fixed child div position in parent div

Tags: css

I want to my child div will be shown inside parent div with same position (absolute) and with same padding (20px). If I put position relative to child div then it will come inside parent div, but i want to use position absolute to child div, But when i run this code The child div goes above the parent div.

```
.parent {
  border:1px solid black;
  height:100px;
  padding:20px;
  position: relative;
  width:400px;
}
.child {
  border:1px solid red;
  height:50px;
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;
}
```

Comment: .parent
 {
    border:1px solid black;
    height:100px;
    padding:20px;
    position: relative;
    width:400px;
}
.child 
{
 border:1px solid red;
    height:50px;
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
}

Comment: It's unclear what your problem is - using absolute position on a child inside a relative positioned parent will allow you to position the child within the parent. Maybe you should create an example jsfiddle to demonstrate your issue?

Comment: You should really revise your question. Code shouldn't be in comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

width % calculates entire width including border and padding.
so all we need is width = 400 - (20 x 2)(padding) = 360 i.e. 90%.

```
.parent { border:1px solid black; height:100px; padding:20px; position: relative; width:400px; }
.child { border:1px solid red; height:50px; position:absolute; display:block;width:90%;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set child div width property to inherit, It will work perfectly.

```
.parent { border:1px solid black; height:100px; padding:20px; position:   relative; width:500px;} 
    .child { border:1px solid red; height:50px; position: absolute; width: inherit;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add this to child div.

```
width: inherit;
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want it to honor the parent(i.e accept the 20px padding), don't absolutely position it then